# Smartgwt 3.0 update to 3.1 running error

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

After I put the smartGwt update to version 3.1 running appear such a mistake：

> > [ERROR] [hnwdmp] Unable to load module entry point class com.smartgwt.client.SmartGwtEntryPoint (see associated exception for details)
> >
> > #### com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): $wnd.isc.Date.setNormalDateDisplayFormat is not a function
> >
> > ```
> > at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
> > at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
> > at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
> > at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
> > at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
> > at com.smartgwt.client.util.I18nUtil.initMessages(I18nUtil.java)
> > at com.smartgwt.client.util.I18nUtil.init(I18nUtil.java:32)
> > at com.smartgwt.client.SmartGwtEntryPoint.onModuleLoad(SmartGwtEntryPoint.java:297)
> > at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> > at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
> > at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
> > at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
> > at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
> > at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
> > at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
> > at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
> > at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
> > ```

Could you tell me how to solve，thx very mush.

Comment: Try doing Cleanup of project, browser cache clearing & deleting gwt-unitcache folder generated in war folder of your application.

Comment: I have done ,but is not the problem.

Comment: Have you compiled your code with new smartgwt jars?